# how to open a specific node using angularJS from dynamic datasource

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to seek assistance on how to open a specific node using `angularJS` from `dynamic data source`. I'm able to toggle (hide/show) the sub nodes but then what I want to happen is when i click on specific node it will only show the specific nodes. Cause currently what happening is when i click on the toggle image it will hide/show all of the sub-nodes.

I'm using the `<img src="#" class="sub-tree" ng-click="toggleNodes()" />` 
as my trigger

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="node in (currentDraft.OrgChartData.SearchList | filter: searchText)" >
    <div class="staff-officer" ui-tree-node
         data-type="staff"
         ui-tree-handle>
        <img ng-src="{{userImage(staff.StaffNumber)}}" class="staff-img img-responsive img-circle" />
        <p class="staff-name" style="">
            {{node.StaffName}}
        </p>
        <img src="#" class="sub-tree" ng-click="toggleNodes()" />
    </div>


    <ul ui-tree-nodes
        data-type="position"
        drag-enabled="false"
        ng-model="node.Positions"
        ng-show="!node.collapsed && node.Positions != null && node.Positions.length > 0"
        class="second-level">
        <li ui-tree-node
            data-type="position"
            data-drag-delay="300"
            data-collapsed="true"
            ui-tree-handle
            ng-repeat="node in (node.Positions | filter: searchText)">
            <span class="staff-position">
                {{node.PositionDescription}}
            </span>
            <div style="height:2px;"></div>
            <ul ui-tree-nodes ng-model="node.nodes"
                data-type="position"
                ng-show=" node.nodes != null && node.nodes.length > 0"
                class="third-level">
                <li ui-tree-node
                    ng-repeat="node in node.nodes"
                    data-collapsed="true"
                    data-can-drag="false"
                    ng-show="toggleMe"
                    ng-include="'new_node_position.html'"
                    data-type="position">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS code

```
    $scope.toggleMe = true;

    $scope.toggleNodes = function () {
        $scope.toggleMe = !$scope.toggleMe;
        //console.log($scope.toggleMe);
    };
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

Add a specific / unique value to each list listed of `toogleMe` and toogle that when clicked. Something like:

```
//adding indexHere which would be unique
<li ng-repeat="node in (currentDraft.OrgChartData.SearchList | filter: searchText) track by $index" >
 .....//yourcode
 //passing that index when onclicked
        <img src="#" class="sub-tree" ng-click="toggleNodes($index)" />
...//your code
//here concat that uinqueID
ng-show="toggleMe{{$index}}"
```

Now in JS:

```
 $scope.toggleMe = true;

    $scope.toggleNodes = function (uniqueVal) {
        $scope.uniqueVal= !$scope.uniqueVal;
        //console.log($scope.toggleMe);
    };
```

**PS:** Though the logic seems right. The above code is untested